# Encrypting System Disk in Alibaba ECS through Terraform

Tags: encryption, terraform, autoscaling, alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

does anyone know how I can Encrypt System Disk in Alibaba ECS through Terraform? Support says it is possible but I can't find any source for that. Thank you in advance!

it seems only possible for data disk
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aliyun/alicloud/latest/docs/resources/ess_scaling_configuration

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/aliyun/alicloud/latest/docs/resources/ess_scaling_configuration#encrypted